# javascript function always return the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following javascript function to check a link and based on the link being a track or album, it should extract the id from the link, but  it'll never go pass the first if statement, it will always alert found track in link, even though I provide a album link, any help would be appreciated.
the links look like the following :

```
https://open.spotify.com/album/1XGo0OD90wIlRccwLe29L9?si=egthfx9CRfuPIhLJ1uXCPA
https://open.spotify.com/track/1SWyGZhn3nyLUZRfWvQ0to?si=Tl-fwsqxQf-J8gZWps2PqQ

function getLinkID(link) {
        if(link.indexOf("spotify")) {
            if(link.indexOf("track")) {
                alert("found track in link");
                var linkID = link.split('track/').pop().split('?')[0];
            } else if(link.indexOf("album")) {
                alert("found album in link");
                var linkID = link.split('album/').pop().split('?')[0];

            }
        } else if(link.indexOf("apple")) {

        } 
        return linkID;
    }
```

Comment: `.indexOf` returns `-1` when it can't find something - which is "truthy" - quickest (but not obvious) fix `if(~link.indexOf("spotify"))`

Comment: Just to expand on  Jaromanda X's comment, -1 is truthy in js

Comment: `~link.indexOf` is 0 (falsey) when `indexOf` is -1 and is a negative number (truthy) otherwise - though `link.indexOf("spotify") >= 0` or `link.indexOf("spotify") > -1` or `link.indexOf("spotify") !== -1` are the usual ways of handling this code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :)

```
function getLinkID(link) {
    if (link.indexOf("spotify") > -1) {
        if (link.indexOf("track") > -1) {
            alert("found track in link");
            var linkID = link.split('track/').pop().split('?')[0];
        } else if(link.indexOf("album") > -1) {
            alert("found album in link");
            var linkID = link.split('album/').pop().split('?')[0];

        }
    } else if(link.indexOf("apple") > -1) {

    } 
    return linkID;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` returns the index number of the match and if there is no match it return `-1`. Also, if there is a match at `first` index, then it will return `0` which is `false` which will break your code. You should use `includes`.

Update from

```
link.indexOf("spotify")
```

to

```
link.includes("spotify")
```

Note, `includes` will not work if you are using IE. For IE either you will need to create a polyfill or update the condition to `link.indexOf("spotify") !== -1`

Comment: with usual "wont work in internet explorer" caveat

Comment: @JaromandaX - Agreed and thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

> function always return the first element

The problem here is that the first condition will be always `true`, only if the index is `0`, even if the word doesn't appear in the link, because `link.indexOf("spotify")` will return an `index` or `-1`.

So when the word isn't not found it will return `-1` which is a `truthy` value, that's why the condition will be `true`, you can confirm this by typing `Boolean(-1)` in the console.

You need to check that the returned `index` is higher than `-1`, so the condition can be evaluated correctly:

```
if(link.indexOf("spotify")>-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf returns -1 if it’s not found and -1 is a truth value. Therefore it will always return true.

Comment: not if indexOf return 0 ... but ...